# How I randomize values in array and insert into particular colomn using mysql query

Tags: mysql

How do I randomize values in array and insert into particular column using MySQL query ?

```
SET @myArrayOfValue = 'WELL,KNOWN,MASK,TEST,JAN,';
SET @myArrayOfValue =LOCATE(',',@myArrayOfValue);
INSERT INTO categories(id,version,category,date_created,is_deleted,last_updated,subcategory) 
VALUES(11,0,(@myArrayOfValue),'2015-01-08 14:11:17',0,'2015-01-08 14:11:17','objective');
```

Comment: I don't get it: do you want to pick a random element from set [WELL, KNOWN, MASK, TEST, JAN] and insert it, or do you want to insert all elements from the set in a random order?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

**Step 1:-**

```
SET @myArrayOfValue = 'WELL,KNOWN,MASK,TEST,JAN,';
```

**Step 2:-now convert you string into array**

```
$myArray=explode(',',@myArrayOfValue);
```

**Step 3:Now shuffle your array**

```
shuffle($myArray);
```

**Step 4:-Now use foreach loop to access each value from array and insert into DB**

```
foreach($myArray as $value)
{
INSERT INTO categories(id,version,category,date_created,is_deleted,last_updated,subcategory) 
VALUES(11,0,$value,'2015-01-08 14:11:17',0,'2015-01-08 14:11:17','objective');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function for that. Try this

```
SET @myArrayOfValue = 'WELL,KNOWN,MASK,TEST,JAN,';
SET @rnd = ROUND(RAND()* (LENGTH(@myArrayOfValue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@myArrayOfValue,',',''))));
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@myArrayOfValue,',',@rnd),',',-1)
```

With

```
LENGTH(@myArrayOfValue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(@myArrayOfValue,',',''))
```

You basically calculate the number of words in the string. And using `RAND()` function you get a random value between *0* and *1*. Then you multiply this by the number of words in `@myArrayOfValue`.

With

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@myArrayOfValue,',',@rnd),',',-1)
```

You're fetching the final word from the string stored in `SUBSTRING_INDEX(@myArrayOfValue,',',@rnd)`. That part of the statement works similar to fetching the array value by its index.

The code may have errors. Please let me know.